# How can i dynamically create an objects of the class?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class `MyClass`:

```
public class OPCTag
{
    public string tagName;
    public string tagOvationMatch;
    public string tagValue;
}
```

I know how to create an object of class manually, but how can i dynamically create and objects of this class ? For example, to create it at the `for` cycle:

```
for (int i=0; i< 10; i++)
{
    //CREATE OBJECT DYNAMICALLY
}
```

To get after it a 10 objects of MyClass.

Comment: Why not a `List<OPCTag>` to store 10 different instances

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking... What's wrong with `new OPCTag()`?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, sorry, i'm novice at it. But i mean i need a 10 objects of MyClass. If i wright something like `MyClass obj = new MyClass()`  that at for cycle, how can i get to the properties of them , if they all will have one name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean simply creating an instance of a class always with the same type, then this will be enough for you:

```
List<OPCTag> list = new List<OPCTag>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // Create object of OPCTag
    var obj = new OPCTag();

    // Set value for 'tagName' property 
    obj.tagName = "New value of 'tagName'";

    // Get value of 'tagName' property
    var tagNameValue = obj.tagName;

    list.Add(obj);
}

// Set value of 4th element 'tagName' property
list[4].tagName = "This is 4th element";

// Get value of 4th element 'tagName' property
var valueOf4thTag = list[4].tagName;
```

But if you want to create classes dynamically with unknown types, you should use reflection:

```
// Type namespace and name
string typeName = typeof(OPCTag).FullName; // MyNamespace.OPCTag

List<Object> list = new List<Object>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // Create object dynamically from string type
    var obj = Type.GetType(typeName).GetConstructor(new Type[0]).Invoke(new object[0]);

    // Set value for 'tagName' property
    obj.GetType().GetProperty("tagName").SetValue(obj, "New value for 'tagName'");

    // Get value from 'tagName' property
    string tagNameValue = (string)obj.GetType().GetProperty("tagName").GetValue(obj);

    list.Add(obj);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think i need to use the first one. But i have a question, after that i will have a 10 objects of  this class at the list, but how can i for example get the info from properties of the 4th element of this list ?

Comment: You should use this: list[4].tagName

Comment: i have an another question if you will, can i store all this instances of a classes in the Dictionary instead of lists?

Comment: @Ramon, you can use Dictionary<string, OPCTag> instead of List<OPCTag>. For add tag to dictionary use should use 'dictionary.Add(obj.tagName, obj)', where tagName property is key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138610/discussion-between-ivan-kishchenko-and-ramon).

Answer (score 1):

You can add your objects dynamically in a loop, but you have to create a list.
You can write something like that :

```
List<OPCTag> lstTag = new List<OPCTag>();

for(int i = 0; i<10 ; i++)
{
     lstTag.Add(new OPCTag());
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But how can i get the info from properties there ?

Comment: As said in other answers, you can read all properties of each elements of your list : `lstTag[index].propertyName = value`

Answer (score 1):

To create 10 objects of `MyClass` you can do, for example:

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    list.Add(new MyClass());    
}
```

Though it's not "dynamically creating objects", just creating instances.

For `Dictionary` you should specify key and value. They can be of any type, not just `int` (usually `string`).

```
Dictionary<int, MyClass> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, MyClass>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    dictionary.Add(i, new MyClass());
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But how can i get the info from properties there ?

Comment: @Ramon, use indexer: `list[1].tagName = "tagName";`

Comment: i have an another question if you will, can i store all this instances of a classes in the Dictionary instead of lists?

Comment: @Ramon, of course you can. Or you can use any other collection: Queue, Stack, Hashset, etc., even Array! You should better read some books on .NET basics.

Comment: You right, i really should :/ But i tried to do it, and i have a System.NullReferenceException when try to add the elements to it. Can you please right the same code, but with dictionary instead of list ?

Answer (score 1):

//Your class

```
public class OPCTag
{
    public string tagName;
    public string tagOvationMatch;
    public string tagValue;
}
```

// Initialize new list object of type OPCTag

```
List<OPCTag> lstTag = new List<OPCTag>();

for(int i = 0; i<10 ; i++)
{
     lstTag.Add(new OPCTag());
}
```

//To read value from lstTag based on index here I specify the 0 index / first value in list.

```
var firstIndexTagname =  lstTag[0].tagName;
var firstIndexTagOvationMatch = lstTag[0].tagOvationMatch;
var firstIndexTagValue =  lstTag[0].tagValue;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It will be awesome to collect all this items in dictionary instead of list, do you know how to do it ?